EF Core does not allow Cascade Delete on 2 foreign keys, but Blazor sample web app does this just fine
I have seen countless posts advising that EF Core with SQL Server blocks multiple foreign keys which have "OnDelete Cascade" (due to cycles and multiple delete paths). However I see in the sample Blazor web app (in VS2022) which installed a default user management database that this is done and works fine without throwing any errors (snippet further below).
My own classes are as right below - just a sample to test this out
EDIT: simplified the example by removing an not necessary Name class. Now this just has the 3 entities in question. Same error reproduced
namespace BlazorSampleEFCore.EFCoreTrial
{
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int DbKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int DbKey { get; set; }
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        
        public Company Company { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GroupId")]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        
        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        [Key]
        public int DbKey { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set;}    
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    }
}

This below is from the initial migration from the sample database which has user management db schema already built in. It has 2 foreign keys on 2 non-nullable columns, pointing to two different principal tables and both with "OnDelete cascade".
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetUserRoles",
    columns: table => new
    {
        UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
            column: x => x.RoleId,
            principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
            column: x => x.UserId,
            principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

How does this pass through Update-Database and get all tables and keys created, but a similar table (see below) added by me refuses to pass through Update-Database:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Employee",
    columns: table => new
    {
        DbKey = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        dob = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
        email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        CompanyId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        GroupID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Employee", x => x.DbKey);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Employee_Companies_CompanyId",
            column: x => x.CompanyId,
            principalTable: "Companies",
            principalColumn: "DbKey",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Employee_Group_GroupID",
            column: x => x.GroupID,
            principalTable: "Group",
            principalColumn: "DbKey",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

On running Update-Database, I get this error:

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Employee] (
[DbKey] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[NameDbKey] int NOT NULL,
[dob] datetime2 NOT NULL,
[email] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
[companyDbKey] int NOT NULL,
[GroupDbKey] int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY ([DbKey]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Companies_companyDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([companyDbKey]) REFERENCES [Companies] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Group_GroupDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupDbKey]) REFERENCES [Group] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Name_NameDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([NameDbKey]) REFERENCES [Name] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Employee] (
[DbKey] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[NameDbKey] int NOT NULL,
[dob] datetime2 NOT NULL,
[email] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
[companyDbKey] int NOT NULL,
[GroupDbKey] int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY ([DbKey]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Companies_companyDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([companyDbKey]) REFERENCES [Companies] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Group_GroupDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupDbKey]) REFERENCES [Group] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Name_NameDbKey] FOREIGN KEY ([NameDbKey]) REFERENCES [Name] ([DbKey]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Employee_Group_GroupDbKey' on table 'Employee' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.


Your three way many-to-many is a little confusing. Companies have Employees and Groups, Groups have Employees and Companies, Employees have Groups and Companies. What exactly is a "Group" here? Why would an Employee have two or more Companies? Can you provide some sample data you are intending to model? The example from the users schema is more straightforward - it is just a many-to-many relationship between users and roles (users can have many roles, roles can have many users).

This is a fictitious example. The main relationship that I need to model is that a Company can have a List of Groups and a List of Employees. However the Group can also have a List of Employees (different from the Employees directly under the Company). That is all.  The other relationships you see are my feeble attempt to provide Navigation properties to act as Foreign Keys from the dependent entities. Essentially the roadblock is that the Employee class has a foreign key to the Company as well as a foreign key to the Group entities. This does not fly with Update-database throwing the error

"This is a fictitious example" ... please take out the fictitious parts as its a waste of time to work on problems that don't exist - even if it is an academic exercise, you still need to create real "test" data to put in your database and have a clear idea of what kind of problem you want to solve with this model. Do you really have employees that work for different companies in the same database? And they belong to groups that belong to yet other companies? I strongly suggest you start with the data - what is the actual data you want to model?

@topsail - I have edited the sample classes to just the 3 that I need. Also, did you see my comment above? The only relationship I need "A Company can have a List of Groups and a List of Employees. However the Group can also have a List of Employees (different from the Employees directly under the Company)". Is there something in my keys that suggests an employee belongs to multiple companies? or to multiple groups?

@topsail I have a (I think) foreign key from the employee to the Company and Group? I believe EF Core cannot find the relationships unless these foreign keys are present. Do they make it possible for an employee to belong to multiple companies or groups?
